# Connection timed out (FRM-92103) with Oracle Forms 11g on Azure Windows Virtual Machine

Tags: oracle, timeout, weblogic

We are running an Oracle database 19c with Oracle Forms 11g on Azure Windows VM. Our config is as follows:

- Azure Windows Virtual Machine

  - Standard B4ms (4 vcpus, 16 GiB memory)
  - Public IP address with an "idle timeout" of 30 minutes (maximum allowed).
  - Oracle Database 19c

Final users access the Oracle Forms application via internet, but from time to time users sessions are disconnected showing:

```
FRM-92103: A network error or server failure has occurred.
```

This is what we have tried so far:

1. Add this line to the "C:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\ClassicDomain\config\fmwconfig\servers\WLS_FORMS\applications\formsapp_11.1.2\config\default.env" file.

```
FORMS_TIMEOUT=10
```

2. Add this line to the "C:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\ClassicDomain\config\fmwconfig\servers\WLS_FORMS\applications\formsapp_11.1.2\config\formsweb.cfg" file.

```
networkRetries=30
heartBeat=2
FORMS_TIMEOUT=10
```

3. Add this lines to the "C:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\ClassicDomain\servers\AdminServer\tmp_WL_user\em\jmb4hf\war\WEB-INF\web.xml" file.

```
    <session-config>
    <!-- Session timeout in minutes -->
        <session-timeout>10</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
```

Even after this changes users sessions keep disconnecting.

Any directions or ideas on this?
Thanks